# How to add plus and minus icon in toggle collapse/expand using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have already toggle collapse/expand div which is working fine but I want to add '+' and '-' icon during expand and collapse.The data is coming from json using loop. I am not getting here where I need to add the icons. Please find the code below.

### compo3.js

```
 import React, { useState,props, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import './home.scss';
    
    class Collapsible extends React.Component {
        render() {
          const { label, children, expanded, expandHandler, id } = this.props;
      
          return (
            <div class="width">
              <div class="border" ><strong>{label}</strong><span className="exp" onClick={() => expandHandler(id)}>+</span></div>
              {expanded === id ? <div>{children}</div> : null}
            </div>
          );
        }
      }
const Compo3 = () => {
    const config = [
        {
        id: 1,
        label: 'Question 1 ?',
        value: 'Answer 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Question 2 ',
        value: 'Answer 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        label: 'Question 3 ',
        value: 'Answer 3'
    },
    ];
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(null);
    const expandHandler = id => {
        setExpanded(id);
        console.log(id)
    };
    var colapseDiv = config.map(function (data) {
        return <Collapsible
            label={data.label}
            id={data.id}
            expanded={expanded}
            expandHandler={expandHandler}>
            <p>{data.value}</p>
        </Collapsible>;
    });
    return (
        <div>
            {colapseDiv}
            <button onClick={() => expandHandler(null)}>Collapse</button>
        </div>
    );
}
  
  export default Compo3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the + and - icons during expand and collapse, you can modify the Collapsible component to conditionally render the + or - icon based on whether the component is expanded or collapsed.

```html
class Collapsible extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { label, children, expanded, expandHandler, id } = this.props;

    return (
      <div class="width">
        <div class="border">
          <strong>{label}</strong>
          <span className="exp" onClick={() => expandHandler(id)}>
            {expanded === id ? '-' : '+'}
          </span>
        </div>
        {expanded === id ? <div>{children}</div> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```